# Docusign help needed

Tags: docusignapi

We are new to Docusign and just trying the sample programs.

We are executing the code for getting the envelope. It is trying to access the below URL

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_informa​tion

We get below exception

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: demo.docusign.net

```
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:196)

  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:530)
```

Is it because of a firewall in our network? Please let us know.

Thanks
..

Answer (score 0):

The Java docs state the following about error **java.net.UnknownHostException**:

```
Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.
```

I've been testing on demo.docusign.net the last two days up until 15 mins ago and I know other devs who are able to connect just fine, so this is likely a problem on your side.  I think the most likely causes are:

- Firewall issue
- Security Software
- DNS issue
- Closed port

If you're able to connect to other https sites then I think you can rule out https (port 443) being closed.  To test your DNS servers try pinging a well known site like google or yahoo and in the terminal window it should translate the address into an ip address.  If it doesn't then you might have a DNS problem.  You should of course also check your firewall settings and logs to see if the requests are being flagged there.  It's most likely that one of these issues are preventing your requests from reaching demo.docusign.net